# Display gridview based on user login in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

How to display gridview based on current user login at index? For example, student A login and fill the form and logout. When other student login, the data that has been filled by student A will not display.

At gridview

```
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'education_id',
        'year',
        'fieldstudy',
        'institute',
        'grade',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

At controller

```
      public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query' => Education::find()->
              where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id ]),
    ]);
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
}
```

At model

```
    class Education extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
   {

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'education';
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['year', 'fieldstudy', 'institute', 'grade'], 'required'],
        [['user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['year', 'fieldstudy', 'institute', 'grade'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'education_id' => 'Education ID',
        'student_id' => 'Student ID',
        'year' => 'Year',
        'fieldstudy' => 'Fieldstudy',
        'institute' => 'Institute',
        'grade' => 'Grade',
    ];
}

public  function getId($id)
{
    return static::find(['user_id' => $id]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need retrive  the Education info related  to an user id  and assuming that in the Education model this relation is based on the field   user_id  you could use  `Yii::$app->user->identity->id`

```
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Education::find()->
                  where(['user_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ]),
]);
```

Comment: ..It still fail.  I got this error. The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses. Is in education model I need to put user_id? I still confuse.         @scaisEdge

Comment: I have update the answer ..  eventually update your post and add  the Education model code, and the controller/action code related to you qquestion

Comment: I've edit my post and also  attached education model part . How can I fix at model part? @scaisEdge

Comment: the model seems correct  .. (you have and user_id field that could be used for filter the istance based on actual logged user)  .. then try var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)   and if the vlaue in Education->user_id match the value for Yii::$app->user->identity->id  the dataProvider should work .. try and let me know

Comment: This code is work for me, but after i add value id at user_id table.      'query' => Education::find()->
                  where(['user_id' =>  Yii::$app->user->identity->id ]) .                                           I try to make the value user_id automatically insert to the table after the user add the education. Btw , thanks @scaisEdge for helping me

Comment: If i undetstand right .. tmy answer  solve  the problem  in your question but you  .. have another question ... is this right? or not?